# MUI TypeError after upgrading: "error TS1005: ',' expected" in ClickAwayListener/index.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

After upgrading my project from v5.8.1 to v5.14.18, running `tsc` against my codebase results in a TypeError from the ClickAwayListener type definition file:

```
../../node_modules/@mui/material/ClickAwayListener/index.d.ts:1:45 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

export { ClickAwayListener as default, type ClickAwayListenerProps, } from '@mui/base/ClickAwayListener';
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

From what I can tell, my Typescript doesn't like the type export and would be happy with the word "type" removed. However, I'm surprised to see this error as I have `skipLibCheck` set to true and `node_modules` excluded in my `tsconfig.json`. How can I prevent this error from happening?

##### Versions:

- TypeScript: 4.3.5
- Node: 18.17.1
- @mui/material: 5.14.18

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I'm not importing the module directly. I don't use ClickAwayListener anywhere in my code base and the error referenced is inside the node_modules file, not any file that I wrote

Comment: Sorry I didn't read closely enough

Comment: @EricBarbour Please try to upgrade your typescript version.